# Wrap a type in newtype

Tags: haskell, ghc, deriving, derivingvia

In the following code I got warning `Orphan instance: instance (MonadIO m, Monad m) => GenerateUUID m`

```hs
instance (MonadIO m, Monad m) => GenerateUUID m where
  generateUUID = liftIO nextRandom
```

According to it the solution is either

```
        move the instance declaration to the module of the class or of the type, or
        wrap the type with a newtype and declare the instance on the new type.
```

(or disable the warning hat Internet also suggest)

My problem is that I'm not able to find **how to wrap the type with a newtype?**

Comment: Take a look at Learn You A Haskell for Great Good, to get some fundamentals about Haskell.

Comment: Where is GenerateUUID defined?

Comment: I’m pretty sure you shouldn’t be able to define an instance like this. If you do define an instance `GenerateUUID m`, then this will end up being an instance for _any_ type `m`, and so you won’t be able to define any more `GenerateUUID` instances as they will overlap with your maximally general `m` instance. (This is the case even if you give a constraint `(MonadIO m, Monad m)`, due to how GHC’s instance resolution works.)

Comment: It seems `generateUUID` should be a top-level definition and not a method of a typeclass. Did you create this `GenerateUUID` typeclass? Or is it from a library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a newtype wrapper like this:

```
newtype Foo m a = Foo { unFoo :: m a }
```

If we also want to say "I want `Foo` to have the same instances for `Functor`, `Monad`, `Applicative`... that `m` has, the only difference being that the methods use `Foo m a` instead of `m a`" we can use the [`-XDerivingVia`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=derivingvia#extension-DerivingVia) extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingVia #-}

newtype Foo m a = Foo { unFoo :: m a } 
                deriving (Functor,Applicative,Monad,MonadIO,GenerateUUID) via m
```

Any time the compiler complains about a missing instance for `Foo`, add it to the `deriving` clause.

---

A slight refinement. Suppose we also wanted to "inherit" `Semigroup` and `Monoid` instances. For example: `IO ()` is a `Monoid`, so we might want `Foo IO ()` to be a `Monoid` as well. We need a separate `deriving` clause:

```
newtype Foo m a = Foo { unFoo :: m a } 
                deriving (Functor,Applicative,Monad,MonadIO) via m
                deriving (Semigroup,Monoid) via (m a)
```

Why a separate clause? Because the typeclasses have different kinds. `Functor` has kind `(Type -> Type) -> Constraint` and we are declaring the instance for `Foo m`, which has kind `Type -> Type`.

Meanwhile, `Semigroup` has kind `Type -> Constraint` and we are declaring the instance for `Foo m a`, the "fully applied" type constructor with kind `Type`.

Comment: "inheriting" instances from the wrapped type can also be done with the `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` extension or the `deriving newtype` strategy https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=derivingstrategies#extension-DerivingStrategies but I prefer `DerivingVia` because it is both more explicit and more versatile.

Comment: I just noticed that even with wrapped type, warning is still present when I move "instance" to the diferent fille than Foo...

Comment: @majkrzak why do you need to do that?